# OrgMode table text narrowing issue with links

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table, org-link, narrowing

I have an issue with my `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8) of 2019-04-30` in OrgMode.

I have a table. One of its collumn is filled with internal links (inside document further). And when I try to narrow text (I need to export document it to ODT) in table it says: Cannot narrow field starting with wide link ... .

So, what do I do?

UPD. Sample.

```
* Pivot table

  | ##    | Task                                                                                                                                                     | Time |
  |-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------|
  | <l5>  | <l15>                                                                                                                                                    | <r10> |
  | 1     | [[*Task #1: This task has small description][Task #1: This task has small description]]                                                                                                                 |      |
  | 2     | [[*Task #2: But this task has large, very large, very very large description with many, many subtasks not described yet but must be described next saturday][Task #2: But this task has large, very large, very very large description with many, many subtasks not described yet but must be described next saturday]] |      |


* Tasks

** Task #1: This task has small description

   Simple task 1

** Task #2: But this task has large, very large, very very large description with many, many subtasks not described yet but must be described next saturday

   Simple task 2
```

Comment: Can you add an example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/02T6aAU0 . Just stand your cursor inside the table and press `C-c C-c`

Comment: Can you put the contents of that file into your question, so it's self-standing?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I have updated my post.

Comment: Bumped into the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Ivan Huang, no, I have not

Comment: Bumped into the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: In my case of [[file:path]It helped me to go from [[file:path]] to file:path.   The link works and it is possible to narrow down the column

Comment: @jaromrax I haven't fix it but I stopped using org-mode, sorry